# Crash: passing return value to C++ code and performance improvement about inline assembly language

Tags: c++, inline-assembly

I tried to calculate the result of x = x + sin(degree) * radius.Although I'm totally new to assembly language,I tried it in C++ to improve the performance,then I get the following function:

```
void calcu()
{
    //double x;
    __asm
    {
        mov ecx,989680H
        mov eax,0
        start:
        push eax
        fldpi
        fmul
        mov ebx,0B4H
        push ebx
        fdivp st(1),st
        fsin
        mov eax,5
        push eax
        fmul
        fadd
        add eax,1EH
        fistp x
        loop start
    };
}
```

- The first problem is that the program crashes when I call this
  function. After a little debug I found that the statement `push eax` is
  the one. How can this happen when I tried to push a value into the
  stack?
- The second one is that you may notice there is a comment at the top
  of this function since I don't know how to get the return value of
  the assembly statements to the variable x.
- The last question is that does assembly code runs much faster than C++ version when I tried to call this function 10,000,000 times?

Comment: Your assembly version has a lot of chances of running a lot slower considering that you don't even know how to make it work..

Comment: Haven't tested, but I don't think you'll get much improvement in speed... There's nothing the machine language can do that C++ can't do either, if you turn on optimisation.

Comment: If you have good optimizing compiler and only average assembly knowledge, your assembly code will not run any faster. Assumption that just coding something in assembly makes it faster by default is wrong.

Comment: I'm seeing a lot of `push`es and no `pop`s; and there seems to be a `loop` with an incredibly large value in `CX`. You're growing the stack by 12 bytes per iteration, and there are 0x989680 iterations; so it is no great surprise you run out of stack space before that completes and crash on a `push`. Unfortunately I can't for the life of me work out what the code is actually *intended* to do. Perhaps you could explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to learn assembly, I would seriously recommend writing C or C++ code and inspecting the generated assembly for your target of choice.

This will give you a basis.

```
#include <cmath>

double compute(double x, double degree, double radius) {
  return x + std::sin(degree) * radius;
}
```

Gives the following LLVM IR:

```
define double @_Z7computeddd(double %x, double %degree, double %radius)
                             nounwind uwtable readnone
{
  %1 = tail call double @sin(double %degree) nounwind readnone
  %2 = fmul double %1, %radius
  %3 = fadd double %2, %x
  ret double %3
}

declare double @sin(double) nounwind readnone
```

Which gives the following assembly:

```
    .text
    .globl  _Z7computeddd
    .align  16, 0x90
    .type   _Z7computeddd,@function
_Z7computeddd:                          # @_Z7computeddd
.Ltmp1:
    .cfi_startproc
# BB#0:
    subq    $24, %rsp
.Ltmp2:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 32
    movsd   %xmm2, 16(%rsp)         # 8-byte Spill
    movsd   %xmm0, 8(%rsp)          # 8-byte Spill
    movaps  %xmm1, %xmm0
    callq   sin
    mulsd   16(%rsp), %xmm0         # 8-byte Folded Reload
    addsd   8(%rsp), %xmm0          # 8-byte Folded Reload
    addq    $24, %rsp
    ret
.Ltmp3:
    .size   _Z7computeddd, .Ltmp3-_Z7computeddd
.Ltmp4:
    .cfi_endproc
.Leh_func_end0:


    .section    ".note.GNU-stack","",@progbits
```

Note that there is still a `sin` call.

Comment: Fine,it's a good way.Do you know how to generate the assembly code in Eclipse with gcc?Thank to @moonshadow,I know why it crashes.

Comment: @user957121: I do not know how to configure the gcc command line from Eclipse, but if you use the `-S` switch gcc will emit the assembly for your file. It might be best to do it in isolation (for a single file). Note that the assembly emitted is heavily tied to the optimization level, so you might want to crank it up (`-O2`, `-O3`, `-Oz`, ...)

Comment: Ok,I got it. I'll compile the code under command line and specify the parameter.Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are in luck, I just finished a ultra fast sine function, which doesn't even need assembly. On my machine it's 8 times as fast as glibc's `sin` function.

Any `float` is legal input, and it will return sinus of that float. Note that this is an approximation, the worst error is 0.000296, the average error: 0.000124 and the average relative error: 0.02%.

If you define CC_FAST_TRUNC it will use a bit hack to quickly round a float to int. This is much faster than simple casting, but requires IEEE754 floats and that the FPU is in double-precision mode. So for portability don't define it.

```
#include <math.h>

/* #define CC_FAST_TRUNC */

/*

    Approximation of sin(x) by the formula f(x) = ax^5 + bx^3 + cx

    Constants chosen such that:

        f(pi/2) = 1
        f'(pi/2) = 0
        f(pi/6) = 1/2

    Resulting in:

        a =   9 / (4  * pi^5)
        b = -41 / (8  * pi^3)
        c = 201 / (64 * pi)

*/

inline float fast_sin(float x) {
    const float a =  0.00735246819687011731341356165096815f;
    const float b = -0.16528911397014738207016302002888890f;
    const float c =  0.99969198629596757779830113868360584f;

    long k;
    float x2;

    #ifdef CC_FAST_TRUNC
    union {
        double d;
        long i;
    } dtoi_hack;
    #endif

    /* find offset of x from the range -pi to pi */
    #ifdef CC_FAST_TRUNC
    dtoi_hack.d = M_1_PI * x + 103079215104.5;
    k = dtoi_hack.i >> 16;
    #else
    k = (long) (M_1_PI * x + copysign(0.5, x));
    #endif

    /* bring x into range */
    x -= k * M_PI;

    /* calculate sine */
    x2 = x * x;
    x *= c + x2*(b + a*x2);

    /* if x is in an odd pi count we must flip */
    x -= (2 * (k & 1)) * x; /* trick for x = (k % 2) == 0 ? x : -x; */

    return x;
}
```

This is taken from my project [commonc](http://github.com/nightcracker/commonc/).

Comment: @MatthieuM. Really? I find it pretty unclear, if I'm honest to myself :P

Comment: That's pretty cool,isn't it?Thank you for your excellent work!